# Getting system Timezones in different languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

I'm currently getting the list of all timezones like this:

```
var TheListOfAllTimezones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

So for instance, the timezone in Paris has a `DisplayName` property of `W. Europe Standard Time`. Now how do I get this list in another language? For instance, for users in France, I'd like to display `Heure Europe de l'Ouest`.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For a better understanding of this problem, read [my blog on the subject](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/12/26/localized-time-zone-names-in-net/), and check out [this library](http://mj1856.github.io/TimeZoneNames/) for a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Changing the `CurrentCulture` doesn't work** as the information comes from the registry (XP) or from the Multilingual User Interface (MUI) DLL (Vista, Windows 7).

On Vista or Windows 7, you may install other languages and change the display language (*Region and Language* -> *Keyboards and languages* -> *Display language*). A reboot is required. This, and only this, will actually change the language used in `TimeZoneInfo`.

On Windows 7, only Ultimate and Enterprise allow the installation of other languages - by means of installing *Multilingual User Interface Packs*.

Once you installed other languages, you should be able to find the DLLs in the *system32* folder (look for `tzres`) and maybe export the resources with Visual Studio.

As to **credible/official sources** - how about [an article on msdn of the BCL Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx):

> ...the display strings are loaded either from the **Multilingual User
>   Interface (MUI) DLL**, tzres.dll, or straight from the registry, when
>   MUI support is unavailable. MUI-enabled operating systems such as
>   Windows Vista contain `MUI_Display`, `MUI_Std`, and `MUI_Dlt` keys, which
>   are indirectly controlled by the operating systems regional settings.
>   On down-level platforms such as Windows XP and Windows Server 2003,
>   only the `Display`, `Std`, and `Dlt` keys exist. **The `Display`, `Std`, and `Dlt`
>   key values are localized only in the default language of the operating
>   system.**

So what did they write about `CurrentUICulture` ?

> Because of the Windows time zone registry architecture,
>   **CurrentUICulture settings do not impact the values of these
>   TimeZoneInfo properties**.

Comment: It does beg the question as to why the DisplayName property is so badly documented...

Comment: I honestly don't know, but unless you create your own virtual machine with a different language setting, my bet would be on english.

Answer (score 2):

If the `CurrentCulture` of your thread is French ("fr-FR"), and if that language is "native" with your Windows version, then the properties `StandardName` and `DaylightName` will be in French, it seems.

**Edit:**

It doesn't look like changing the `CurrentCulture` of the thread will help. The time zones all come from the Registry (see Jim Mischel's answer for the path), and it looks like the language of the Windows installation determines the values. The IDs (which are keys in the Registry path) are always in English, while the other properties depend on the Windows language.

What is your output of the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.DisplayName);

var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine(tzi.Id);              // always English
Console.WriteLine(tzi.DisplayName);     // localized
Console.WriteLine(tzi.StandardName);    // localized
Console.WriteLine(tzi.DaylightName);    // localized
```

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, it seems that it depends only on the Operating System language. I'm trying this on a Danish-language Windows machine. For one `TimeZoneInfo` instance, I have `Id` equal to `"Romance Standard Time"`; and `DisplayName` is `"(UTC+01:00) København, Stockholm, Oslo, Madrid, Paris"`; and `StandardName` is `"Rom, normaltid"`; and `DaylightName` is `"Rom, sommertid"`.

Comment: Yup, it's really weird that there's no built-in way to get that list in different languages.

Comment: @JonSkeet: any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @frenchie: Unfortunately not :( The normal approach is to give a list of cities instead of time zone names - Unicode CLDR gives example cities to list, but then those are for TZDB time zones...

Comment: @JonSkeet: ok, may be I too should stick to the city list then. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but even names of cities can be localized. For example the Italian capital _Roma_ is called _Rom_ in Danish and German, and _Rome_ in English and French. Other city names, like _København_ (_Copenhagen_) can have even more different names in different languages.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, and I *think* CLDR has different names for the cities for different languages. I'd have to check though.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx):

> The collection returned by this method is sorted by display name using
>   the current culture.

Have you tried changing the current culture to the user's culture before getting the list?

That might not work. It's possible that the only display names available are those for the Windows version that's installed. That is, if you have a US-English version of Windows, the French display names might not be there. Looking at my Registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`), I see only the English names.

Comment: Interesting. I have a Danish version of Windows here, and I see `Std` and `Dlt` in the Registry in Danish. In the `.NET` object, I see the `Id` property in English, and the `StandardName` and `DaylightName` properties in `Danish`.

Comment: Yup, it's really weird that there's no built-in way to get that list in different languages. My OS is in English and the app will be hosted on Azure so I guess that'll be in English too.

Answer (score 0):

How about to create some class like "TimeZoneInfoExtension" which will have static method named like ToLocolizedString:

```
public static class TimeZoneInfoExtensions
{
    public static string ToLocalizedString(this TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        switch (timeZone.Id)
        {
            case "Dateline Standard Time":
                return i18n.DatelineStandardTime;

            case "UTC-11":
                return i18n.UTC11;

            case "Hawaiian Standard Time":
                return i18n.HawaiianStandardTime;

            case "Alaskan Standard Time":
                return i18n.AlaskanStandardTime;

            ....

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Where i18n is a class with resources. And yes, you have to fill translations manualy. But I just used something like this in different system languages to generate translations:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[ +-]");
foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine("  <data name=\"{0}\" xml:space=\"preserve\">", rgx.Replace(timeZone.Id, string.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine("    <value>{0}</value>", timeZone.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine("  </data>");
}
```

And then you can get use it depending on your CurrentCulture like so:

```
foreach (var timeZoneInfo in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.ToLocalizedString());
}
```