# Get TimeZone from browsers with OS set to some other language

Tags: javascript, jquery

In French windows(windows 7 OS language set as French) i am using the following code to get the time zone name but i am getting the time zone name in French language which i wanted in English.

```
   function getTimeZone() {
        return /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];
   }
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163241/getting-system-timezones-in-different-languages

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246547/get-name-of-time-zone

Comment: for now i am manually comparing the TimezoneOffset value and returning the time zone name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe javascript's native implementation will give you an output in different languages. You'll have to use a library with i18n like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks jeremy bt i can't use any other library.