# System TimeZone Display in English Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code hosted in a System where the OS language is Japanese and I am getting the timezone's display in Japanese language. I set the Globalization setting in web.config to English but no luck. Is there any way to get the display in English text.

```
<select id="timezone" name="timezone">
    @foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()) {
        <option value="@timeZone.Id">@timeZone.DisplayName</option>
    }
</select>
```

Screenshot of the User Interface

[image]

Comment: might be a problem connected to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163241/getting-system-timezones-in-different-languages

Comment: I have the permission to  host my site in hosting environment and do not have any permission to install any language pack.

Comment: Yes, it's dependent on OS localization, not .NET's globalization features.  This has been documented in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Also, see [my blog on this subject](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/12/26/localized-time-zone-names-in-net/) and try out [this library](http://mj1856.github.io/TimeZoneNames/) for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, but then you'd have to maintain it if the host's operating system time zones are updated (in case timezones change... and they **DO** change). If you don't control the host, this might be a real pain in the ass.

I've made it for you (you can check it [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9CJtDB) ... disregard all the boilerplate code, it's the default code in dotnetfiddle for MVC, I just changed the view):

```
@functions{
  string GetTimeZonesInEnglish(string timeZoneId, string defaultDisplayName)
  {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Dateline Standard Time"," (UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" },
        { "UTC-11"," (UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11" },
        { "Hawaiian Standard Time"," (UTC-10:00) Hawaii" },
        { "Alaskan Standard Time"," (UTC-09:00) Alaska" },
        { "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)"," (UTC-08:00) Baja California" },
        { "Pacific Standard Time"," (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)" },
        { "US Mountain Standard Time"," (UTC-07:00) Arizona" },
        { "Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)"," (UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan" },
        { "Mountain Standard Time"," (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)" },
        { "Central America Standard Time"," (UTC-06:00) Central America" },
        { "Central Standard Time"," (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)" },
        { "Central Standard Time (Mexico)"," (UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey" },
        { "Canada Central Standard Time"," (UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan" },
        { "SA Pacific Standard Time"," (UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco" },
        { "Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)"," (UTC-05:00) Chetumal" },
        { "Eastern Standard Time"," (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" },
        { "US Eastern Standard Time"," (UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)" },
        { "Venezuela Standard Time"," (UTC-04:30) Caracas" },
        { "Paraguay Standard Time"," (UTC-04:00) Asuncion" },
        { "Atlantic Standard Time"," (UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)" },
        { "Central Brazilian Standard Time"," (UTC-04:00) Cuiaba" },
        { "SA Western Standard Time"," (UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan" },
        { "Newfoundland Standard Time"," (UTC-03:30) Newfoundland" },
        { "E. South America Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Brasilia" },
        { "SA Eastern Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza" },
        { "Argentina Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) City of Buenos Aires" },
        { "Greenland Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Greenland" },
        { "Montevideo Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Montevideo" },
        { "Bahia Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Salvador" },
        { "Pacific SA Standard Time"," (UTC-03:00) Santiago" },
        { "UTC-02"," (UTC-02:00) Coordinated Universal Time-02" },
        { "Mid-Atlantic Standard Time"," (UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic - Old" },
        { "Azores Standard Time"," (UTC-01:00) Azores" },
        { "Cape Verde Standard Time"," (UTC-01:00) Cabo Verde Is." },
        { "Morocco Standard Time"," (UTC) Casablanca" },
        { "UTC"," (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time" },
        { "GMT Standard Time"," (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" },
        { "Greenwich Standard Time"," (UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik" },
        { "W. Europe Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna" },
        { "Central Europe Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague" },
        { "Romance Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris" },
        { "Central European Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb" },
        { "W. Central Africa Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) West Central Africa" },
        { "Namibia Standard Time"," (UTC+01:00) Windhoek" },
        { "Jordan Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Amman" },
        { "GTB Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest" },
        { "Middle East Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Beirut" },
        { "Egypt Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Cairo" },
        { "Syria Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Damascus" },
        { "E. Europe Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) E. Europe" },
        { "South Africa Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria" },
        { "FLE Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius" },
        { "Turkey Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Istanbul" },
        { "Israel Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Jerusalem" },
        { "Kaliningrad Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Kaliningrad (RTZ 1)" },
        { "Libya Standard Time"," (UTC+02:00) Tripoli" },
        { "Arabic Standard Time"," (UTC+03:00) Baghdad" },
        { "Arab Standard Time"," (UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh" },
        { "Belarus Standard Time"," (UTC+03:00) Minsk" },
        { "Russian Standard Time"," (UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd (RTZ 2)" },
        { "E. Africa Standard Time"," (UTC+03:00) Nairobi" },
        { "Iran Standard Time"," (UTC+03:30) Tehran" },
        { "Arabian Standard Time"," (UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat" },
        { "Azerbaijan Standard Time"," (UTC+04:00) Baku" },
        { "Russia Time Zone 3"," (UTC+04:00) Izhevsk, Samara (RTZ 3)" },
        { "Mauritius Standard Time"," (UTC+04:00) Port Louis" },
        { "Georgian Standard Time"," (UTC+04:00) Tbilisi" },
        { "Caucasus Standard Time"," (UTC+04:00) Yerevan" },
        { "Afghanistan Standard Time"," (UTC+04:30) Kabul" },
        { "West Asia Standard Time"," (UTC+05:00) Ashgabat, Tashkent" },
        { "Ekaterinburg Standard Time"," (UTC+05:00) Ekaterinburg (RTZ 4)" },
        { "Pakistan Standard Time"," (UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi" },
        { "India Standard Time"," (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi" },
        { "Sri Lanka Standard Time"," (UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura" },
        { "Nepal Standard Time"," (UTC+05:45) Kathmandu" },
        { "Central Asia Standard Time"," (UTC+06:00) Astana" },
        { "Bangladesh Standard Time"," (UTC+06:00) Dhaka" },
        { "N. Central Asia Standard Time"," (UTC+06:00) Novosibirsk (RTZ 5)" },
        { "Myanmar Standard Time"," (UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)" },
        { "SE Asia Standard Time"," (UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta" },
        { "North Asia Standard Time"," (UTC+07:00) Krasnoyarsk (RTZ 6)" },
        { "China Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi" },
        { "North Asia East Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Irkutsk (RTZ 7)" },
        { "Singapore Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore" },
        { "W. Australia Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Perth" },
        { "Taipei Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Taipei" },
        { "Ulaanbaatar Standard Time"," (UTC+08:00) Ulaanbaatar" },
        { "North Korea Standard Time"," (UTC+08:30) Pyongyang" },
        { "Tokyo Standard Time"," (UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo" },
        { "Korea Standard Time"," (UTC+09:00) Seoul" },
        { "Yakutsk Standard Time"," (UTC+09:00) Yakutsk (RTZ 8)" },
        { "Cen. Australia Standard Time"," (UTC+09:30) Adelaide" },
        { "AUS Central Standard Time"," (UTC+09:30) Darwin" },
        { "E. Australia Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Brisbane" },
        { "AUS Eastern Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney" },
        { "West Pacific Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby" },
        { "Tasmania Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Hobart" },
        { "Magadan Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Magadan" },
        { "Vladivostok Standard Time"," (UTC+10:00) Vladivostok, Magadan (RTZ 9)" },
        { "Russia Time Zone 10"," (UTC+11:00) Chokurdakh (RTZ 10)" },
        { "Central Pacific Standard Time"," (UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia" },
        { "Russia Time Zone 11"," (UTC+12:00) Anadyr, Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky (RTZ 11)" },
        { "New Zealand Standard Time"," (UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington" },
        { "UTC+12"," (UTC+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12" },
        { "Fiji Standard Time"," (UTC+12:00) Fiji" },
        { "Kamchatka Standard Time"," (UTC+12:00) Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky - Old" },
        { "Tonga Standard Time"," (UTC+13:00) Nuku'alofa" },
        { "Samoa Standard Time"," (UTC+13:00) Samoa" },
        { "Line Islands Standard Time"," (UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island" },  
    };
    string retVal;
    if(dict.TryGetValue(timeZoneId, out retVal))
      return retVal;
    return defaultDisplayName;
  }             
}
```

And then:

```
<select id="timezone" name="timezone">
    @foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()) {
        <option value="@timeZone.Id">@GetTimeZonesInEnglish(timeZone.Id, timeZone.DisplayName)</option>
    }
</select>
```

I made some simple console utility to output the strings in "dictionary initializer format" from an English machine, just in case you want to update them:

```
using System;               
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
            Console.WriteLine("{ \"" + timeZone.Id + "\",\" " + timeZone.DisplayName + "\" },");
    }
}
```

Check it out [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XmnOnr)

All this said, since the time zones display names are found using the registry of the host's operating system and are language dependant... while what I said above "works" if they never update, I'd say it's just not the best way to handle it.

I'd personally handle my own timezones if I was not in control of my host, in my database or whatever... you can find an updated timezone database [in the IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) or in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you are up to datamine it.

There's also the [Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) from Unicode, which is generally better suited at showing time zones to users (disregarding many redundant time zones) and provides its (easily parseable) XML file in many languages

And of course, there's also [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) by none other than Jon Skeet (et al.) which you may want to check. I **think** it maintains its own Olson Timezone Database, but I'm not all that sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a string table with your values in English. You access the string table either server side (as you do above) or client side and use the values therein to populate your drop down.

Sample JSON file:

```
{
"timezones":{
    "en":{
        "standard":[
            {"zone":"(UTC-5:00)",
            "title":"Eastern Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-6:00)",
            "title":"Central Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-7:00)",
            "title":"Mountain Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-7:00)",
            "title":"Phoenix Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-8:00)",
            "title":"Pacific Standard Time"}
        ],
        "daylightSavings":[
            {"zone":"(UTC-4:00)",
            "title":"Eastern Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-5:00)",
            "title":"Central Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-6:00)",
            "title":"Mountain Standard Time"},
            {"zone":"(UTC-7:00)",
            "title":"Pacific Standard Time"}
        ]   
    }
}
```

}

Sample (client side) Implementation

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var inDaylightSavings = false;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                // TODO - set in daylight savings.

                // Load data from local json file
                $.getJSON("tz.json", function(obj) {
                    var targetDataset = obj.timezones.en.standard;
                    // Adjust for U.S. daylight savings
                    if(inDaylightSavings){
                        targetDataset = obj.timezones.en.daylightSavings;
                    }

                    // Update the dropdown 
                    $.each(targetDataset, function(key, value){
                        $("#selectTimezones").append("<option>" + value.zone + " " + value.title + "</option>");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Select Timezone</label>
        <select name="timezones" id="selectTimezones">
            <option value="None" selected="Selected">- not selected -</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwYJs.png)